# how to search threw a multidemsional array to find a specfic value in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array in the format like this:

```
 array(2) {
   [0]=>
   array(8) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(2) "12"
     ["recipient_id"]=>
     string(2) "18"
     ["sender_id"]=>
     string(2) "13"
     ["unread"]=>
     string(1) "1"
     ["notifications_type"]=>
     string(16) "booking.accepted"
     ["notifications_parameters"]=>
    string(24) "Booking request accepted"
     ["reference_id"]=>
     string(2) "12"
     ["created_at"]=>
     string(19) "2017-05-09 20:34:42"
   }
   [1]=>
   array(8) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(2) "13"
     ["recipient_id"]=>
     string(2) "18"
     ["sender_id"]=>
     string(2) "13"
     ["unread"]=>
     string(1) "1"
     ["notifications_type"]=>
     string(23) "booking.paymentrequired"
     ["notifications_parameters"]=>
     string(28) "Payment required for booking"
     ["reference_id"]=>
     string(2) "12"
     ["created_at"]=>
     string(19) "2017-05-09 20:34:42"
   }
 }
```

I want to do an action in my code when the value of the $nofications_type matches any of these three options:

```
// booking.requested
// booking.accepted
// booking.rejected
```

booking.accepted and booking.rejected are for the $user_id

booking.requested is for the $coach_id

the array could have 3 possible entries for each request, which are referenced on the reference_id value in each of the arrays in the multidimensional array

```
            //remove the notification for the booking request as the user has now viewed it
            if ($user_id == 1) {

                //messy code - just in case this booking is accepted
                $notifications_type = "booking.accepted";
                ModelNotifications::newInstance()->updateUserNotification($userId, $notifications_type, $id);
                //messy code - just in case this booking is accepted       

                $notifications_type = "booking.rejected";

            } elseif ($coach_id == 1) {

                $notifications_type = "booking.requested";

            }

        ModelNotifications::newInstance()->updateUserNotification($userId, $notifications_type, $id);

        // more code
```

doing an if-else and calling my model inside the first if section to check if the value is booking.accepted doesn't look good, what would be the best way to do this ??

Comment: are you trying to read the array or create it? I ask because it seems you are setting the type in the following code: `$notifications_type = "booking.accepted";`

Comment: I have the array already so it would be reading it

Comment: $nofications_type is set from the array values, I then do a action with this value in my ModelNotifications

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement is perfect for checking something against multiple possible cases

```
switch ($booking["notification_type"]) {
   case "booking.accepted":
        // do what you need for accepted
        break
   case "booking.requested":
        // do what you need for requested
        break
   case "booking.rejected":
        // do what you need for rejected
        break
}
```

You could also combine it with other cases, for example where the `$notification_type == "booking.accepted" && $user_id == 12` but then your switch would be `switch (true) { ...`